# Querying a range of cells where each cell value should return a different result - Excel VBA ADODB

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I've been at this for awhile now, and I haven't been able to figure this out...

I'm attempting to write a macro to query a variable range of IDs from a Teradata database. I can get it to work if passing only one ID as a parameter to the command, but I haven't been able to find a way to query the full range. Currently there are 2456 different IDs within the range (cells B2:B2456). The end result is expected to be: ID / .

From trawling the net, it would appear a loop would be needed to query all individual IDs. This surprises me, as I would have thought there was a way to pass the full range at once. I tried concatenating all values to the one cell but this returns no result.

If possible, I want to find a way to query the full range without the need to pass each ID to a separate query. Any tips on where I can get started?

EDIT: I've since found that the variable number of IDs can be referenced in the SQL query - i.e. SELECT from TABLE where ID IN (?,?,?,?,?...), with the number of ? specifying the number of parameters it will accept. Based on this, I'm thinking a loop can add the full list of parameters, however I'm stumped thinking how I can relate this to the number of ? in the SQL query...

```
Set Command1 = New ADODB.Command
Set Param1 = Command1.CreateParameter("ID", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 203, Wb2.Range("C1").Text)
Command1.Parameters.Append Param1


Command1.CommandText = " select distinct ID, Price from TABLE where ID IN ? "
Command1.CommandType = adCmdText
Command1.CommandTimeOut = 240

Set connect = GetNewConnection
Command1.ActiveConnection = connect

Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rec1 = Command1.Execute()

Wb.Activate

With Wb.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=Wb.Range("A1"))
.Name = "data"
.FieldNames = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


rec1.Close
connect.Close
Set rec1 = Nothing
Set connect = Nothing



 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by concatenating all the values as " ('ID1','ID2','ID3'...'ID2045') and assigning it a variable. Interesting, because this is essentially what I originally tried, the difference being that I manually concatenated the values in Excel then pointed back to the cell in VBA (i.e. Range("C1").Text) which had the effect of returning no result.

I'm very keen to understand better ways of writing this, as I believe using a string variable leaves you open to SQL injection (?). In any case, this is giving me the desired results, which was always to query a variable range of IDs, and return the ID + its associated Price.

```
Sub SQLQueryContinued2()

 Dim connect As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim wb As Worksheet
 Dim Wb2 As Worksheet
 Dim Param() As ADODB.Parameter
 Dim Command1 As ADODB.Command
 Dim lrow As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim ConcatSQL As String


 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
 Set Wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
 lrow = Wb2.Range("B" & Wb2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 'Concatenate desired range into one cell
 For i = 0 To lrow - 4
 ConcatSQL = ConcatSQL & "'" & Wb2.Cells(i + 2, 3) & "'" & ","
 Next i
 ConcatSQL = "(" & Left(ConcatSQL, Len(ConcatSQL) - 1) & ")"

 'Open Command Object with One Paramter
 Set Command1 = New ADODB.Command

 With Command1
    .CommandText = " sel distinct ID, Price from TABLE where ID IN " & ConcatSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandTimeout = 600
 End With


 'Connect to Data Source
  Set connect = GetNewConnection 'Represents Private Function with Connection String
  Command1.ActiveConnection = connect

  Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rec1 = Command1.Execute()

  'Paste Results
  wb.Activate

 With wb.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rec1, Destination:=wb.Range("A1"))
 .Name = "data"
 .FieldNames = True
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

 'Close Connections
 rec1.Close
 connect.Close
 Set rec1 = Nothing
 Set connect = Nothing

 End Sub
```